# unnecessary constructor in react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

If you need to specify initial state in a class, I see people did this

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() { super(); this.state = { user: [] } }
   render() {
      return <p>Hi</p>
   }
}
```

but what's wrong without a constructor?

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = { user: [] }
   render() {
      return <p>Hi</p>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> but what's wrong without a constructor?

There is nothing "wrong" with it. But it uses the [***class properties* proposal**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) which is not officially part of the language yet (since you tagged the question with [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6): It is **not** part of ES6). So you have to correctly configure your build system to be able to use it (in addition to what's needed for JSX).

Comment: Just an addition to Felix's answer: If you don't want to use the constructor (I'm not a fan of it) you can also use componentWillMount to set the state with setState(...). Then you don't need the super() call which saves a few lines of code.

Comment: @Tobias isn't it just simply do state = {myapp:'something'} will do? why need to setState with componentWillMount at all?

Comment: Well most of the time I‘m not just setting static values, but computed ones. That‘s not possible with class properties. To unify my code I use componentWillMount everywhere